# Bells Spaceship Paradox using radar coordinates

Tags: special-relativity

Consider the traditional Bell spaceship paradox with two spaceships moving to the right, one with constant proper acceleration $\alpha_1$ and the other with $\alpha_2$. Using fermi coordinates (ie. Rindler coordinates in this case) we find that in order for the spaceships to maintain the constant proper length L' between them, the accelerations of the spaceships must differ according to $$L' = \frac{1}{\alpha_2} - \frac{1}{\alpha1}$$ Now consider the same problem but using Radar coordinates instead. For a given proper time $t_1$ we can parametrize the line of constant $t_1$ as seen in the inertial frame as

$$T_1(x_1) = \frac{1}{\alpha_1}e^{\alpha_1 x_1}\sinh(\alpha_1 t_1)$$

$$X_1(x_1) = \frac{1}{\alpha_1}e^{\alpha_1 x_1}\cosh(\alpha_1 t_1)$$

We now want to find where this line intersects the worldline of spaceship 2, given by $$0 = \frac{1}{2 \alpha_2} \ln(\alpha_2^2(X^2-T^2))$$ Doing this, we arrive at the expression $$L'
 = \frac{\ln\alpha_1 - \ln\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}$$ The problem is of course that this result does not agree with the one we get using fermi coordinates. And worse yet, it will give a different magnitude depending on if we are looking at spaceship 1's or spaceship 2's frame.

The purpose of this thought experiment is to really probe about the proper use of radar coordinates.
It appears there must be a "true" answer to the question of what the difference in the rockets proper acceleration must be so that a string between them won't break. But the currently accepted answer is that given by fermi coordinates. So is there a sense in which fermi coordinates correspond to "physical" values of position and time whereas radar coordinates do not? Are there certain situations where we cannot use fermi coordinates to get a sensible answer, and/or which will give inconsistent results with that given by fermi coordinates? And what are we to make of that? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second $L'$ seems to be a difference of coordinate positions. To get the physical distance between the spaceships, you need to integrate $ds$ over a line between them. In Rindler coordinates, $ds=dx$ when $dt=0$, so the physical distance is the difference of coordinate positions, but in radar coordinates, $ds=e^{α_1x}dx$. Do the integral and you'll get the first $L'$.

> So is there a sense in which fermi coordinates correspond to "physical" values of position and time whereas radar coordinates do not?

For position, yes, in the sense that $ds=dx$. For time, they're both the same.

Rindler coordinates are analogous to polar coordinates, with $x\leftrightarrow r$ and $t\leftrightarrow θ$. Radar coordinates are analogous to conformal polar coordinates, i.e., the Mercator projection (but applied to a flat Earth). The Bell spaceship paradox is analogous to the fact that when you're running in circles around the pole, you have to turn more sharply the closer you are to it.